# Create or emulate a single XML file or .ZIP (like .docx file) from a set of XML, DTD and XSL files

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a nested folder structure structure containing dozens of various files (XML, DTD, XSL) with XML files referencing other DTD, XSL, and other XMLs (which can also reference other files). I.e. something like this (I removed some similar lines for brevity):

all.xml - root file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE notification [
    <!ELEMENT notification ANY>
    <!ENTITY % types SYSTEM "dtd/types.dtd">
    <!ENTITY % from SYSTEM "dtd/from.dtd">

    <!ENTITY types_en SYSTEM "lang/en/types.xml">
    <!ENTITY from_en SYSTEM "lang/en/from.xml">
    <!ENTITY subj_ru SYSTEM "lang/ru/subjects.xml">
    <!ENTITY desc_en SYSTEM "lang/en/descriptions.xml">

    <!ENTITY regexp_en SYSTEM "lang/en/placeholders.xml">

    %types;
    %from;
]>

<notification>
&types_en;
&from_en;
&templ_fr;
</notification>
```

lang/en/descriptions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../../xsl/descriptions.xsl"?>
<!--DOCTYPE descriptions SYSTEM "../../dtd/descriptions.dtd"-->
<descriptions lang="en">
```

And so on. So, there is a root file which includes DTDs and many other files which also include their own DTDs and XSL tables (different ones for different XMLs).

I need to find the way to merge them all into a single file. All solutions I found so far we either about merging several independent XML files or about adding a single DTD to a file (while in my case different DTDs are applied to different files and not all XMLs are independent because they are nested). The result of a single XML fine would be great.

Or, I'd almost be happy if I was able to just pack all the folders into a single file (.zip) and later read it like MS .docx format (where .ZIP file represents an isolated filesystem with working references between contained files). The file is processed with my own C# software so I don't need to bother about compatibility with other XML readers. But I don't know any method in .NET which would allow me to read and XML-parse a .ZIP file like a filesystem.

Or, maybe there is a method to catch any attempt to access any resource (be it another XML, DTD or XSLT) when parsing XML data with XmlTextReader? The purpose is to be able to intercept all requests to missing files and supply the contents of the requested resources to the XmlTextReader when it requests them.

Right now, I'm researching if System.IO.Packaging (OpenXML) can serve this purpose.

Comment: https://github.com/FrozenCow/sharpfilesystem

Comment: Thank you, will try it as the last resort if nothing else helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last question, you could create an `XmlReader` with one of the static `XmlReader.Create()` methods that accept `XmlReaderSettings`. You could setup the settings with a custom implementation of `XmlResolver` class which would override `ResolveUri()` and `GetEntity()` methods. In these methods you could intercept requests to a missing file and handle it with the logic you have. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't get how to use this method. It just lets me replace the URL to the resource but I don't have any URI to substitute. I can have file content for substitution (i.e. nested XML file contents) but not its URI. If I could inject the file contents into URI, this would work but I don't think it's possible.

Oops, missed GetEntity part. This helps, will give it a try!